# JavaScript на стороннем хостинге

Tags: javascript, хостинг

Доброго времени суток! Проблема в том, что на платформе `Blogger` не всегда возможно вставить JavaScript в html шаблона, раньше для таких скриптов я использовала хостинг на Народе. Народ - замечательный хостинг, но последние 5 дней он был не доступен, значит в моих блогах и блогах моих читателей `javascript`'ы не работали. Такое положение меня устроить не могло и теперь я залила скрипты на свой платный хостинг.

Итак, есть `hostA` и  `hostB` на обоих из них лежит `MyScript.js` сейчас в html `Blogger'а` есть запись

```
<script src='http://hostA/MyScript.js'/>
```

Как её модифицировать, чтобы по недоступности `hostA` скрипт брался с `hostB`?

Спасибо.

Comment: Либо оформить скрипты так чтобы они проверяли - не загружены ли уже сами, либо на сделать что то типа роутера на своём стабильном хостинге - в html будез загрузка с host3 а сервер на host3 тыркается по всем возможным хостам и возвращает с первого успешного.

Comment: Я бы на вашем месте разместил всю статику на [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) и забыл бы про всякие "народы", как про страшный сон.

Comment: Спасибо! Народ, в общем-то не так уж плох с 2007 года это его первая осечка. Если бы у меня были бы только кусочки статики в дополнение к "народу" добавила бы и Amazon... Но потребности у меня немного посерьезней поэтому у нас хостинг на hostgator и еще в Исландии. Так что хостингов нам хватает, просто от народа я проблем как-то не ожидала, вот и не побеспокоилась "пока гром не грянул" :(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, например, поставь две ссылки на скрипт подряд, сначала с левого хоста, затем на свой
в яваскрипте на левом хосте обьяви переменную, например `var hostA = true;`.

В скором скрипте проверяй наличие этой переменной, если она есть, значит скрипт 1   загрузился и второй уже грузить не нужно, иначе - грузим.

Comment: > Ну, например, поставь две ссылки на скрипт подряд, сначала с левого хоста, затем на свой

Так тогда оба скрипта всегда будут грузиться.

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать наверное ещё такой вариант через jquery например:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.ajax({url:"http://hostA/script.js", dataType:"script"})
     .fail(function(){
           $.ajax({url:"http://hostB/script.js", dataType:"script"});
});
</script>
```

Если надо чтобы на момент загрузки Html js ы грузанулись надо добавить `async:false` в ajax запрос, иначе можем начать использовать скрипт до того как он загрузиться (если ожидать аналогичность работы `<script>` тега)